# How to find the sum in a series when the common difference is alternated?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The problem is as follows:

> Find the sum of the first 16 terms in:
>   $$1,3,9,11,17,19,...$$

So far I was only able to find that the common difference between the terms goes from $2,6,2,6,...$ however in the second difference the sign is alternated $4,-4,4,...$ therefore making it impossible to use a second degree polynomial to create a recursion formula. What is the method that should be used to find the sum and the formula for the terms?.

Edit:

Is it possible to obtain a recursion formula which can be used for the whole sequence?.

Comment: If you only need the first 16 terms, wouldn't it just be faster to calculate only those rather than creating a whole formula for them?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: you have two arithmetic sequences

$$1,9,17...\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\;3,11,19,... $$

So you have to sum first $8$ in each of them...

Comment: Its a nice observation, but although it solves the problem, isn't there another option which does not involve splitting the sequences?

Comment: Well you could sum every two consecutive terms and you get 4,20,36,...an arithmetic sequence with difference $d=16$. Now you sum up first 8 terms...

Comment: Thanks. This solves half of the problem. But I'm wondering if it can be obtained a formula that can be used to reproduce the sequence without splitting it in halves?. If this cannot be done, why?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Whoever designed the problem made it in such a way that there would be two separate APs. I think it is one of those type of "trick questions", where it is an unconventional sequence of numbers. If you're only looking for a formula, then I think Markus answer is correct. Otherwise, the approach by ChristianF is the easiest.

Answer (score 2):

> A recursion formula adding alternatively $2$ and $6$ is e.g.
>   \begin{align*}
> &a_0=1\\
> &a_n=a_{n-1}+2+2(1+(-1)^n)\qquad\qquad n\geq 1
> \end{align*}

Here we *build* the wanted sequence behaviour from known simple ones:

\begin{align*}
((-1)^n)_{n\geq 1}&=(-1,1,-1,1,-1,\ldots)\\
(1+(-1)^n)_{n\geq 1}&=(0,2,0,2,0,\ldots)\\
(2(1+(-1)^n))_{n\geq 1}&=(0,4,0,4,0,\ldots)\\
(2+2(1+(-1)^n))_{n\geq 1}&=(2,6,2,6,2,\ldots)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you please add more steps to explain how to reach the recursion formula you proposed?. I'm stuck at trying to get the idea. -i'm familiar with $(-1)^{n}$ that specifies the sign but I don't know why you put that inside the bracket.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: I've added an explanation which might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry to reply late. Now I can understand what you did. If you don't mind, don't forget to correct the error in the fourth line of your recursion formula, there is a $0$ next to the $6$, it should be $2$ right?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: Good to see the approach is clear now. Typo corrected, thanks.